# Assets Manager Update and FinishLoading

Tags: libgdx, assets

When should I use `update()` vs `finishLoading()` ?
I use `assetManager.load()` then `finishloading()` in show() method of my screen I don't use `update()`

Comment: The wiki entry may help: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets. Use update() for asynchronous loading, in case you want to do other stuff (like show a progress bar). Use finishLoading() to block until all your assets are loaded.

Comment: and when using finishLoading() app will work smoothly or not and this method depend on what ?

Comment: Not sure I understand. When finishLoading() returns, asset Manager has finished loading whatever you instructed it to load. You can then use those assets however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need `update()` if you want to show some kind of animation while many objects are loading. It allows you to load stuff one at a time in the render loop so you can continue drawing something animated until it's done (for example, a loading screen with a bouncing ball). If you call `finishLoading()`, the method will block until everything is finished loading, so nothing will animate during that time. The length of time it blocks depends entirely on what and how much you're loading.